# list of regular expresions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to create a list of regular expressions but automatically is added a new '\'

```
a = ['\s+ interface *', '\s+ address', '\s+ priority \d']

>>> a[2]
'\\s+ priority \\d'
```

I try to do something like this

```
with open('conf.txt') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    for s in a:
        if bool(re.match(s, i)):
            print('i')
```

So basically I have a configuration file and I want to find some specific commands (list a). The command has a format for that reason I need a regular expression.

I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
for i in lines:
    if bool(re.match('\s+ interface *', a)):
        print('i')
    elif bool(re.match( '\s+ address', a)):
        print('i')
    elif bool(re.match( '\s+ priority \d', a)):
        print('i')
```

Comment: What is the output of the for loop? Does it print "ok" as you want it to?

Comment: Try making them raw strings `r"regex"`

Comment: Note that '\\' represents a single backslash character. This is expected behavior and means exactly what you want it to. I suggest you learn about so-caled "escape characters" and "escape sequences".

Comment: @PixelEinstein: While the leading `r` should definitely be added, it won't change what's happening here. The problem is one of understanding what the backslashes do; adding the `r` won't remove any backslashes.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably to create the list as a list of regular expressions instead of making a list of strings. You can do this with `re.compile()` as per the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: Please try to be more clear, tell us what output you expect to see.  Also, in your second code, it is not clear what you expect to happen.   For one thing, your search string is not in the list.   That is, the list a, does not contain any string '   priority 34'.  Finally, the list a, does contain single slashes, the problem is how you print the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your list does contain single slashes.  If you want to print the strings, try doing it like this:

```
a = ['\s+ interface *', '\s+ address', '\s+ priority \d']

print( '%s'%a[0] )
```

The output will be,

```
\s+ interface *
```

Note that it has a single slash.

Answer (score 0):

The idea works as expected. My problem was the regular expression itself.